# PHP Hybrid Auth with Facebook - Annoying Facebook API error

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, hybridauth

I'am trying the [Hybrid Auth](http://hybridauth.sourceforge.net/) but I don't know why this does not works.

I have everything in the **index.php**

```
<?php

    use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
    use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

    require 'vendor/autoload.php';

    $app = new \Slim\App();

    // facebook api
    define('FACEBOOK_APP_ID','1583449111670664');
    define('FACEBOOK_APP_KEY','c673d4ec188b72d00a31388d2d31bfdc');

    $container = $app->getContainer();
    $container['hybrid-api'] = function($c) {
        $settings = [

            'base_url' => 'http://localhost/hybrid-auth/auth', 

            'providers' => [ 
                'Facebook' => [ 
                    'enabled' => true,
                    'keys'    => ['id' => FACEBOOK_APP_ID, 'secret' => FACEBOOK_APP_KEY],
                    'scope'   => ['id','name','first_name','last_name','link','locale','email'], 
                    'trustForwarded' => true
                ]
            ],
            'debug_mode' => 'info',
            'debug_file' => 'logs/hybrid-auth.log',
        ];

        return new Hybrid_Auth($settings);
    };

    $app->get('/', function(Request $request, Response $response){ 
        $hybrid = $this->get('hybrid-api');
        $session_user = Hybrid_Auth::storage()->get('user');

        if( empty($session_user) ) {
            echo "<a href='/hybrid-auth/login'>login</a>";
        } else {
            echo "Welcome " . $session_user->displayName . "<br />";
        }
    });

    $app->get('/login', function(Request $request, Response $response){
        $hybrid = $this->get('hybrid-api');
        $adapter = $hybrid->authenticate(ucwords('facebook'));
        $user_profile = $adapter->getUserProfile();

        if( empty( $user_profile ) ) {
            echo 'Error!!'; 
        } else {
            Hybrid_Auth::storage()->set('user', $user_profile);   
            return $response->withRedirect('/hybrid-auth'); 
        }
    });

    $app->get('/auth', function(Request $request, Response $response){
        Hybrid_Endpoint::process();
    });

    $app->run();
```

**composer.json**

```
"require": {
    "slim/slim": "^3.0",
    "hybridauth/hybridauth": "2.8.2"
}
```

I'am running it on apache2 as a folder. http://localhost/hybrid-auth

I will not extract the Facebook app id and key because it is a test app.

**The error I've got**

[image: Facebook Api Error]

In the Hybrid Auth log everything is ok. Has no error messages.

Comment: I have no idea what that error message is saying. It would be a good idea if you set your FB language to English before taking screenshots like this, so that more people here can understand what the error message is actually saying.

Comment: The message says: We are working to fix this as soon as possible. Tells nothing ...